# Can the Bellman-Ford Algorithm be used to find the longest path in an undirected graph through first negating the weight of all the edges?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, shortest-path

I understand that the Bellman-Ford Algorithm can solve the single-source shortest-paths problem. However, can it also be used to determine the longest path in an undirected, graph through first negating the weight of all the edges?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/17980/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57894/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/88003/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2660/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/125264/755

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by "longest path".  Does it have to be a simple path?  Do you allow visiting the same vertex/edge more than once?  In the future I encourage you to spend some time searching the site before asking; we have many prior questions that cover the longest path problem here.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.